# SQL count(*) grouped by date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, group-by, count

I have a table as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PersonnelRecord;

CREATE TABLE #PersonnelRecord
(
    person_id int NOT NULL,
    company_id int NOT NULL,
    entry_date date NOT NULL,
    exit_date date NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_PersonnelRecord PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

INSERT INTO #PersonnelRecord
    (person_id, company_id, entry_date, exit_date)
VALUES
    (1, 24, '2004-03-17', '2010-12-31'),
    (2, 24, '2011-04-18', '2019-11-28'),
    (3, 25, '2017-02-10', '2019-10-20'),
    (4, 34, '2004-03-17', '2010-12-31'),
    (5, 24, '2004-03-17', '2999-01-01'),
    (6, 24, '2010-03-20', '2999-01-01');

SELECT *
FROM #PersonnelRecord pr
ORDER BY pr.person_id;
```

[db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=803f099ece099258b0f1f09275deac20)

[image]

So a table that shows when people have entered and exited a company. 2999-01-01 means the person is still at the company.

I would like to add a count to each row of how many people are working at the company at time of the exit date. The result would be:

```
|-----|
|  3  |
|-----|
|  3  |
|-----|
|  1  |
|-----|
|  1  |
|-----|
|  2  |
|-----|
|  2  |
|-----|
```

How could I achieve that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Could you please provide your table structure as DDL (in text in the question) and your data as DML (same deal) - you could also use a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) - but be sure to post any data that's on the fiddle here also.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What didn't work as you expected?

Comment: Hi, Thomas - I've updated your question with the sort of demo script that @Vérace was describing.  Having that should help make it easier for folks to answer your question.  Please keep that approach in mind if / when you have further questions on the site!

Comment: @JoshDarnell wouldn't this be something that would be asked on StackOverflow.com not here?

Comment: @Edward I think it's a fuzzy line.  The solution necessarily involves subqueries or apply, which is not completely basic.

Comment: Thanks so much for the warm welcome and the help. In the future, I'll make sure to post questions in the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the APPLY operator to count the number of employees active at the termination date.  As I looked at the question at first I missed that there were different companies, so once I added `AND company_id = pr.company_id` to the query I get the result you are expecting.

```
SELECT * FROM #PersonnelRecord pr
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT count(person_id) as person_count FROM #PersonnelRecord
    WHERE pr.exit_date > entry_date 
        AND pr.exit_date <= exit_date 
        AND company_id = pr.company_id
     ) a
ORDER by person_id
```